# Scan a webpage and get the video embed url only

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a search engine on PHP that have indexed some movie sites., Now i want to get the video embed url on a given web page URL . and put it in an iframe. How will i get it ? using python? and integrate it in PHP ? but how will i pass the url from php to python and use the beautifulsoup?

Here is what I'm trying now

```
import BeautifulSoup

html = '''http://www.kumby.com/avatar-the-last-airbender-book-3-chapter-5/'''
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

I've googled, but have not found any good information about this (probably because I don't know what this is called to search for), does anyone have any experience with this and knows how it can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: `How will i get it ? using python? and integrate it in PHP ? but how will i pass the url from php to python and use the beautifulsoup?` I felt like this was the intro to a particularly titillating python+PHP instructional video. It was not :(

Comment: @admdrew having the same problem? same here dude. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "http://www.kumby.com/avatar-the-last-airbender-book-3-chapter-5/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
l = soup.findall("embed","object","param","video")
for i in l:
  print i.string
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to scrape the webpage and find for following tags and get the video link. You don't  need python to do it.

```
<embed> 
<object>    
<param> 
<audio>
<video>
<source>(<video> and <audio>)
<track> (<video> and <audio>)
```

I made a small hack to scrape all the links from a webpage, refer to this [sample](https://github.com/saran87/link-graph/blob/master/proxy/proxy.php).

Comment: does your sample is for php only? thanks for this.

Comment: does this get the video url?

Comment: it just grabs all <a> tag , if you look for extract_links method in this [file](https://github.com/saran87/link-graph/blob/master/proxy/graph/ScrapperLib.php) the regular expression does the extraction